# iOS: Using HanekeSwift with SwiftyJSON

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, swifty-json

I use Alamofire with SwiftyJSON in my current swift project.
I would like to add HanekeSwift for caching.

Adding HanekeSwift to the project make it "collide" with SwiftyJSON struct JSON.

Is there any easy way to use both of these frameworks?
I know there is a option to rename one of the JSON structs but seems like a stupid workaround. Or do some namespace thing.

Error message:

```
'JSON' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
```

Any solutions to this?

Comment: Where and when does this occur?

Comment: When compiling the project, its a regular red warning.

Comment: And *where* in your code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, the solution that I've found works for me is just to declare the full type of JSON object you are trying to use. E.g. - declare SwiftyJSON.JSON rather than just JSON when expecting or using a SwiftyJSON struct, or Haneke.JSON when you want to use Haneke's JSON enum.

For example, for SwiftyJSON:

```
var json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(inputObject!)
```

or for Haneke:

```
var json = Haneke.JSON(inputObject!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice solution for me at the [HanekeSwift/issues](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift/issues/147).

Inside my class with conflicting imports declared as follows

`typealias JSON = SwiftyJSON.JSON`

Hope it might be usefull for someone