# Haneke crashing SwiftyJSON's 'JSON?' type

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json, haneke

I have a TableViewCell that works just fine. However as soon as I `import Haneke`, I receive error on `var post: JSON? {..` :

> 'JSON' is ambigious for type lookup in this context

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
// import Haneke

class DiscoverTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var post: JSON? {
        didSet {
            self.setupPost()
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I am using pod

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2'
pod 'HanekeSwift'

This is how I declare it in TableViewController:

```
  import Alamofire
  import SwiftyJSON

  var results: [JSON]? = []      // SwiftyJSON's [JSON]

  func smt() {
       ...
       let json = JSON(response.result.value!)

       if let data = json["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
               self.results = data
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Using HanekeSwift with SwiftyJSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855910/ios-using-hanekeswift-with-swiftyjson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be same `typealias`.

You can use `SwiftyJson` like this:

```
let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(response.result.value!)
let result = Haneke.AnyFunction()
```

Comment: When I try `let json = Haneke.JSON(response.result.value!)`, I receive `'JSON' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

Comment: You should use SwiftyJSON for JSON parsing. Haneke.JSON was an example.